# Load string resource with AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class main extends AppCompatActivity{

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String[] main_drawer_items;
    main_drawer_items = // load from resources array?
...
```

Above method is the main entry point of the app. I need AppCompatActivity for supporting a ActionBar. How to load strings from strings.xml?
This one here does not work:

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_drawer_entries);
```

It does not find "getResources".

Comment: Try to initialize main_drawer_items inside the onCreate method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lazy initialisation, because context is null at the moment you are trying to perform getResources(). getResources() is the same as context.getResources(). Doing init in onCreate method is the best choice for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `context.getResources.getStringArray(R.array.main_drawer_entries);`
You can use `Fragmentactivity` or `ActionBarActivity`.